# Why fgets works fine with two calls?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm newbie in C (couple of years). I would like to know why `fgets()` works fine with two calls, rather than one. The variables are:

```
  FILE *dat;
  int i; 
  char buff [22];
  char *file; 
  i = 0;
  dat = fopen(file__dat, "r");
```

Here is the code with two calls:

```
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        fgets(buff, 22, dat);
        printf("%s\n", buff);
        file = strtok(buff, ",");
        strcpy (aparell [i].Name, file);
        file = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(aparell[i].MAC, file);
        fgets(buff, 22, dat);
    }
```

with one call:

```
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        fgets(buff, 22, dat);
        printf("%s\n", buff);
        file = strtok(buff, ",");
        strcpy(aparell [i].Name, file);
        file = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(aparell[i].MAC, file);
    }
```

The file is:

```
CTRL-000,31A0E321456C
CTRL-001,AE45F3123BAA
CTRL-002,2956FECA24A3
CTRL-003,AA345FCC23FA
CTRL-004,FA345778123A
CTRL-502,34F45A3423DD
```

Thanks you in advance. :)

Comment: What does "works fine" mean? You literally get the same output with both versions of the code? More to the point, where do you ever output anything to test that?

Comment: Does the real file have empty lines like what you have in the question?

Comment: Your input file seems to have empty lines between each line with usable data. You should test whether the line is empty (buff[0] == '\n' or something like strlen(buff) < 5) and skip processing it if that's the case.

Comment: Could you add the ouput your get for each code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `fgets(buff, 22, dat);` reads at most 21 bytes from the stream, which happens to be exactly the number of bytes of the first line before the newline sequence: `CTRL-000,31A0E321456C`.

The subsequent `strtok()` calls do find the tokens and the line is parsed correctly.

In the next iteration of the loop, `fgets(buff, 22, dat);` reads the newline and stops there, causing the second `strtok` to fail and return `NULL`. Since you do not test the return value, `strcpy (aparell[i].MAC,file);` has undefined behavior because `file` is a null pointer.

When you add an *extra* `fgets()`, the newline is read and ignored and the next iteration read the following line.

You should fix the code by increasing the buffer size and testing the return values of `fgets()` and `strtok()` to avoid undefined behavior. You should also consider `\n` as a separator to avoid including it the last field.

Here is an improved version:

```
char buff[128];

for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    if (!fgets(buff, sizeof buf, dat)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing input\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("%s", buff);
    file = strtok(buff, ",\n");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        break;
    }
    strcpy(aparell[i].Name, file);
    file = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        break;
    }
    strcpy(aparell[i].MAC, file);
}
```

Note that you should also check the lengths of the strings before copying into the structure fields with `strcpy()`.

Note also that `strtok()` has a shortcoming when it comes to parsing input: it considers any sequence of separators to be a single separator. Hence it cannot handle empty fields such as `,31A0E321456C` or `CTRL-000,`

Answer (score 1):

With

```
fgets (buff, 22, dat);
```

you read *exactly* the amount of character on the line, ***except one***: The *newline* at the end of the line.

If you read only 22 character, the `fgets` will not read the newline, leaving it for the second `fgets` to read (as an empty "line").

Increase the size of `buff` by one (to `23`) and use `sizeof buff` as the size. Then `fgets` will read all of the line including the newline from the file. (And hope the format of the file will not change with longer lines.)

This behavior is well documented. From e.g. [this `fgets` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

> Reads at most `count - 1` characters from the given file stream...

Comment: `fgets` will read at most **21** bytes if given an argument size of `22`...

Comment: fgets reads the newline at the end of the line and stores it in the buffer. His problem seems to be alternating empty lines or some problem with the interpretation of UNIX/DOS CR+LF combinations.

Comment: @FBergo Those empty lines is probably because the OP doesn't know how to format properly in the question. And because of translation the code will see *only* a newline.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is about. Each line in the file is 21 bytes, meaning `fgets` will read all 21 and stop before reading the newline.

Comment: @chqrlie Correct, and then the 22:nd character will be the terminator. But the lines are 22 character including the newline (or 23 if on Windows, but that will be translated into a single newline character).